# How use function on window parent?

Tags: javascript

Use this code for close window, then I try to call the function on parent window - but it doesn't work.

```
window.opener.$(\'body\').append(\'<script type="text\/javascript">update_rows("250");<\/script>\');
top.close();
```

Comment: doe you get any errors in the **Developer Tools** **_console_** when you try to run this syntactically incorrect javascript? ... you seem to have a problem with your keyboard ... the \ key seems to be triggering a lot ... it's not **EVER** needed in the code you posted

Comment: @Happy_Cougar there's no need to escape  your quotes, do that for string literals.

Comment: are you want to access update_rows() function of parent window?

Answer (score 0):

This is why:

The code you use is this:

> ```
> window.opener.$(\'body\').append(\'<script type="text\/javascript">update_rows("250");<\/script>\');
> top.close();
> ```

You are escaping the quotes that isn't needed. Use this:

```
window.opener.$('body').append('<script type="text/javascript">update_rows("250");</script>');
top.close();
```

I have no idea where you got that from, but it's wrong.

Comment: @JaromandaX it should work, unless the window us already closed.